# p:datatable - update ManyToMany property results in LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces, lazy-initialization

I've got two Entities in a ManyToMany relationship.
"User" and "Car".

I have a *p:dataTable* of all users, including a column with the used cars of each user:

**XHTML**

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable value="#{usersPM.users}" var="user">
  <p:column>
    <p:inputText value="#{user.name}">
      <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{usersPM.onEdit(user)}"/>
    </p:inputText>
  </p:column> 
  <p:column>
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{user.cars}">
      <f:selectItems value="#{usersPM.allCars}" />
      <p:ajax />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Now, I want to update the list of cars of a user using the *p:selectCheckboxMenu*.
There's no save-button - everything should be processed via ajax (works fine for the name btw).

The *p:selectCheckboxMenu* component contains all the available cars. Out of those, the currently assigned cars are correctly selected for each user.

As soon as I try do modify the list, I am receiving:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed

**Whats the problem here? Users and Cars are loaded - otherwise they would not be displayed correctly (?)**

*Entities / Beans following:*

```
@Entity
public class User{
   @ManyToMany
   private List<Car> cars;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Car{
   @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "cars" )
   private List<User> users;
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UsersPM{
  private List<Car> allCars;
  private List<User> users;

  @PostConsruct
  public void init(){
    users = userDao.findAllAndLoadCars();
    cars = carDao.findAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this issue you should supply the type of the collection to the component with attribute `name=”collectionType”`.

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{user.cars}">
  <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{usersPM.allCars}" />
  <p:ajax />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

**Read More:**

- [Hibernate LazyInitializationException And p:selectCheckboxMenu](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-and-pselectcheckboxmenu/)